# Will dd work, if cloning from a healthy image to a disk with bad sectors?

Tags: filesystems, dd, block-device

I have a raspberryPI failing to boot from `sdcard1`. Luckily, I had made its image with `dd` several months before.
I have written that image to another sdcard and it started booting, all is well here.

Now, going back to `sdacrd1`. It works well, when attached to a card-reader, no tools find any issues with it. I assume it has bad sectors, and wonder **what will happen, if I `dd` that image back to `sdcard1`?**

I know that `dd` reads/writes block-level, does it mean, if some block XXX from the image is dead on the disk, it will skip and just go to XXX+1? Or is it clever enough to skip the bad block, just like most filesystems do?

Comment: `dd` will need extra parameters if you want it to skip and pad out bad sectors, and unless you use those parameters, it will just exit with an error.  It is not “clever”.

Comment: When an SD card shows signs of failure, you can analyze it according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035). It may look good when you copy to it, but after reboot you may find that it was not storing what was written to it.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge SD cards will, like SSD, detect bad sectors and avoid writing to them ever again, so you might be fine writing the original image to the SD card that failed before.

Personally I would not trust that SD card any longer. You never know when the next cell will fail, but wear leveling makes it likely at least some more are at the end of their lifetime. If you're really hard on budget, you can try, but be prepared to do the same thing again very soon.

The blocks would look the same to dd, by the way, wear leveling is done by the controller on-chip.
See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/27619/is-it-true-that-a-sd-mmc-card-does-wear-levelling-with-its-own-controller

Comment: "you might be fine writing the original image to the SD card that failed before" -- just for the sake of experiemnt, I am doing that now and will try to boot from it.

Comment: Luckily, I have 1 more SD card, which powers RPI now.

Comment: +1 for "I would not trust that SD card any longer."